# What is a permalink?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am working on a joomla project. I was asked to change the permalink of my site. What should I do and what is the purpose of doing it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a definition of this word then it is:

> a permanent static hyperlink to a particular web page or entry in a
>   blog.

If you want to know how to change permalink then here is the answer:

1. Login to administrator panel
2. Go in Menu Manager
3. If it is Article permalink then create new menu item from menu manager
4. Select Single Article as Menu Type and then Select your Article
5. Leave "alias" box blank it will automatically choose alias based on your Menu Item Name.
6. Click on Save Button.

You can follow the same procedure for other types of components like Category, Contact etc.

Comment: how can i change the permalink of a custom component

Answer (score 1):

permalink is nice looking link to your article. Without menu aliases it will be less pretty, like `example.com/component/content/1-article_alias` but you can do many variants of pretty links, create alias for category where you displaying article plus create alias for that article, then you will have a pretty link like this `example.com/category-menu-alias/article-menu-alias` and that's help your viewers read the page, but seo won't get any advantage, because google index well links with ID and numbers.

regards